# How to stop Windows authentication when redirecting a specific .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My application is written using ASP.NET MVC. There is a controller where a method named `GetReport` returns and redirect to an `.aspx` page.

This is working perfectly on localhost. But when application runs on remote server then `GetReport` method requires Windows authentication:

```
public ActionResult GetReport()
{
    return Redirect("~/Reports/Report.aspx?keyword=divisions&jobCode=");
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the `GetReport` method that "requires" Window authentication - most likely it's the **target .aspx page** you're trying to navigate to that's set up to request Windows credentials ......

Comment: @marc_s In **web.fonfig** file I changed  `<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />` for that specific file but issue remains still.

Comment: Is Report.aspx a "container" for a ReportViewer control?  If so the authentication request may be from SSRS.  Just a thought.